# Nodejs Workflow Management Using Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Typescript seems to be a better choice for writing code where the code base is huge and requires more consistency.

But the examples and experiences I find around the internet are more on the client side, may be coz of the Angular2.0 decision to use AtScript/Typescript.

Though Typescript adds a lot of power to Javascript, there is something that keeps on pissing me off. How do I manage codebase with duplicate files. My understanding is I have two ways to do it.

### 1st Way

Use a build tool like gulp/grunt, watch for changes, and compile Typescript to Javascript in the same folder. This may look something like this:

```
├── models/
│ ├── User.ts
│ ├── User.js
│ ├── Likes.ts
│ ├── Likes.js
```

### 2nd Way

Another way will be the same but of instead of outputting Javascript into the same folder, I can clone the entire workspace:

```
├── typescript
│ ├── models/
│ │ ├── User.ts
│ │ ├── Likes.ts
├── javascript
│ ├── models/
│ │ ├── User.js
│ │ ├── Likes.js
```

Both are not the best solution for me. Is there any other way to manage codebase for nodejs. For client it is simple as we have only one output file.

Comment: Another option is to extend require function with https://github.com/eknkc/typescript-require

Comment: You can configure your build to output a single javascript file if that is what you want

Comment: Who wants a single output file for server code ?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to manage codebase for nodejs. For client it is simple as we have only one output file

No. We personally try to go with the second.

With the JS excluded from the REPO and rebuilt pre npm publish.